# Clipping Issue with JLayeredPane + JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlayeredpane

**Scenario:** Inside a viewport of a `JScrollPane` I have multiple `JLayeredPane`. Each `JLayeredPane` have at least one `JPanel` with an image (set by `paintComponent`).

**Issue:** Hard to explain without seeing (code below): when scrolling the `JScrollPane`, the Images inside the `JLayeredPane`s that aren't fully inside the `JScrollPane` area are not drawn.

If I continue scrolling, eventually the `JLayeredPane` will be fully in the `JScrollPane` area, and the images are drawn.

**Why do I think the problem is in `JLayeredPane`?** 
If I replace the `JLayeredPane` with a `JPane` the issue is gone.
The code provided can show both cases. Set the first, and only, static variable of the public class: `public static boolean forceProblem = true` to control this.

**Question:** What am I doing wrong or what to do to solve the issue? I need to keep using the `JLayeredPane` (or anything else that can do the same).

**Reproducing the issue:**

1. Run the code below.
2. Scroll the vertical bar all the way down.
3. Scroll the horizontal bar all the way right: **issue: the upper line of images arent loaded**
4. Slowly scroll the vertical bar up: the images are loaded when fully into the Scroll area.

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class MYimagePanel extends JPanel {
    public Image image; 

    public MYimagePanel( Image img ) {
        this.image = img;
        this.setLayout( null );

        this.setBounds(0, 0, 1, 1); 
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        this.setSize( 100 , 100 );
        this.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 100 , 100 ));     

        g.drawImage( this.image , 0 , 0 , 100 , 100 , null );
    }
}

class MYcomposedImagePanel extends JLayeredPane {
    public MYcomposedImagePanel( Image img ) {
        this.setLayout( null );

        MYimagePanel myImgPane = new MYimagePanel( img );

        this.add( myImgPane );
        this.setLayer( myImgPane , 1 );

        this.setBounds( 0, 0 , 100 , 100 );
        //this.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 100 , 100 ));  
    }
}






public class ClippingProblem extends JFrame {
    public static boolean forceProblem = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() { 
                // Creating Frame
                JFrame frame = new ClippingProblem();

                Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
                contentPane.setLayout( null );

                // ScrollPane viewport
                JLayeredPane imagesPane = new JLayeredPane();
                imagesPane.setLayout( null );
                imagesPane.setLocation(0, 0);
                imagesPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(2000,2000));

                // ScrollPane
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( imagesPane  ); 
                scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, 1000 , 700 );
                scrollPane.getViewport().setScrollMode(JViewport.SIMPLE_SCROLL_MODE);

                contentPane.add( scrollPane );

                // Add Images
                int offset = 0;
                MYcomposedImagePanel composedImage;
                MYimagePanel myImagePanel;
                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon( "image.png" );

                for( int y = 0 ; y < 1900 ; y = y + 100 ) {
                    for( int x = 0 ; x < 1900 ; x = x + 100 ) {
                        if( forceProblem == true ) {
                            composedImage = new MYcomposedImagePanel( icon.getImage() );
                            composedImage.setBounds( x + offset , y , 100 , 100 );
                        imagesPane.add( composedImage );
                    } else {
                        myImagePanel = new MYimagePanel( icon.getImage()  );
                        myImagePanel.setBounds( x + offset , y , 100 , 100 );
                        imagesPane.add( myImagePanel );
                    }
                    offset += 10;
                }
                // Set visible
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        } ) ;
    }


    public ClippingProblem() {
        setSize(1024, 768);

        setTitle("Clipping Problem");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

Image Used:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using SetBounds after adding the JPanel to the JLayeredPane solved the issue:

```
 class MYcomposedImagePanel extends JLayeredPane {
    public MYcomposedImagePanel( Image img ) {
        this.setLayout( null );

        MYimagePanel myImgPane = new MYimagePanel( img );

        this.add( myImgPane );
        this.setLayer( myImgPane , 1 );

        myImgPane.setBounds( 0, 0 , 100 , 100 ); // <<--- NEW LINE ----

        this.setBounds( 0, 0 , 100 , 100 );
        //this.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 100 , 100 ));  
    }
 }
```